# Скобки (ли) помогут убежать от тире?

Tags: пунктуация

> И встречаются там человек из монастыря, вокруг головы которого нимб –
>   значит это святой и мужчина в короне – значит василевс какой – в очень
>   красивой одежде.

*И встречаются там человек из монастыря, вокруг головы которого нимб (значит, это святой), и мужчина в короне (значит, василевс какой), в очень красивой одежде.*

Так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все мне нравится, кроме последней запятой. А если так:

И встречаются там человек из монастыря, вокруг головы которого нимб (значит, это святой), и мужчина в короне (значит, василевс какой) **и** в очень красивой одежде.

Answer (score 0):

А кто с кем встречается в оригинальном контексте? Или они оба "нам" встречаются? Что-то меня смущает в предложении в каждом из этих вариантов.

Если это не встреча мужчины и человека, тогда предлагаю сказать так:

**Встречаются там и человек из монастыря, вокруг головы которого нимб (значит, это святой), и мужчина в короне (значит, василевс какой) и в очень красивой одежде.**

Но и в этом варианте последнее "и" мне всё равно не нравится. И слово "василевс" тоже подозрительное. В моих словарях встречается только "басилевс".

Или всё же их встреча? Тогда предлагаю "встречаются ... человек ... с мужчиной ...".

Comment: Тут может быть нюанс... Не просто человек и мужчина, а: *человек из монастыря*... Немножко тайны. Это пересказ фрески. А "василевс" проходит по всему тексту.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Я к тайнам не придираюсь. Я только предлог "с" имел в виду, а в многоточиях всё сохраняется. То есть, я предложил одну из конструкций: либо "встречается кто-то с кем-то", либо "встречаются и кто-то, и кто-то ещё" — в зависимости от смысла фразы (которого я так и не понял точно).

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Я откорректировал ответ. Неудачно я слово "рандеву" использовал — не то имел в виду.

Comment: Гриззли, они не "нам" встречаются, а *там,* на фреске... Предлог ***с*** уже летит автору!